# What instead of iframe ? Subdomain issue

Tags: html, iframe, subdomain

Let's assume there's a site - http://domain.com

Now my job is to upload a CMS (Joomla, version 1.7). However, there's a big mess on FTP - already a Joomla (version 1.5), forum software, many unknown PHP files, many custom folders.

I can't simply upload Joomla 1.7, because I would have to delete that Joomla 1.5 file by file. So I've decided to upload CMS to subdomain, http://domain.com/subdomain, and display that content from http://domain.com. I don't want to simply redirect, because original URL must be kept.

How to do it? iframes are pretty outdated.

Comment: Trash the lot and restart? Sounds like a total mess, and will be hell to maintain and keep patched.

Comment: yeah doing anything but backing up the server before starting fresh sounds like more trouble then its worth, and you are just asking for trouble down the line, not to mention headaches

Comment: Do you mean deleting all that? (Sorry, I've got problems with English, not my native) I would like to do that very much, but not my server :(

Answer (score 1):

Iframes ? Stay away, use rewrite rules and keep the domain clean

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: That sound reasonable. So how to use it properly ? Should I add something to .htaccess file?

Comment: http://www.blogsdna.com/754/top-5-online-htaccess-mod-rewrite-rules-generator-website-blogs.htm

One of these will do, really that's the basics, you should be aware of that if you're running a server.

Answer (score 0):

iFrames are still heavily used today and would be a fine solution for you.  However there would be some problems with using an iframe that you should consider.  My two cents fix the problem correctly by install Joomla properly, then try the using re-write rules all else fails you can use iframes.

Bad Points for iframe solution:

- Using an iframe pointing to your site would probably be really bad for SEO.  I don't think google or bing would look into the iframe thus you'd get 0 SEO value out of this solution.
- URL link's would be ruined, if a user wanted to bookmark, tweet the url,
  or even just send it to a friend they would have no way of doing that
  because the url would be changing in the iframe not in the browser
  bar.

No so bad points for iframes:

- Sounds like this is an easy workaround for your problem so its not very time consuming.
- iFrames are used all over the place on the internet and are fully supported by all major browsers.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Re-write could work. Do you know maybe how to configure it properly?